# php array sorting on child element

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, associative-array

I am trying to sort an array based on the **first** *[0]* child element.  But in my code the keys are being replaced by the array number in the sort:

```
$myArray = array(
    'my last row' => array(  
         '0' => 'ZZZZ',
         '1' => 'AAAA'
     ),
     'the first row' => array(
         '0' => 'AAAA'
     )
  );
usort($myArray, 'cmp' ) ;

var_dump($myArray);

function cmp    ($a, $b)        {
        return ( ( $a[0] > $b[0] ) ? 1 : -1 );
}
```

result:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>       // should be ['the first row']  *not* [0]
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "AAAA"
  }
  [1]=>        // should be ['my last row']  *not* [1]
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "ZZZZ"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "AAAA"
  }
}
```

The sort order itself appears to be working as expected.

I would like to see the following:

```
the first row  => AAAA
my last row   =>  ZZZZ, AAAA
```

This is probably a very simple issue, but I cannot resolve it.

Thank you very much.

EDIT:  this sort does not involve the key itself, but rather a child-element key.  i believe that makes this question unique.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort multidimensional array PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042018/sort-multidimensional-array-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keeping array index key when sorting a multidimensional array with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425117/keeping-array-index-key-when-sorting-a-multidimensional-array-with-php)

Comment: "Don't Panic"'s suggestion of using "uasort" worked great, but he seemed to have removed his answer.  if you want to put it out there again, i would be honored to select that as the correct one.

Comment: @edwardsmarkf I deleted it after I found what I thought was a duplicate. It still looks like a duplicate to me, to be honest. Maybe take a look at that one again? Their comparison function is different, but the main point of it is that they're having the same issue with the keys not being preserved.

Comment: Dont Panic - you are correct it was a duplicate, sorry.   But your solution worked out great.   Sadly, i have discovered this takes a HUGE performance hit, so i am looking into doing the sort on the client side instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
It will maintain your index associations.

```
$myArray = array(
'my last row' => array(  
     '0' => 'ZZZZ',
     '1' => 'AAAA'
 ),
 'the first row' => array(
     '0' => 'AAAA'
 )
```

);
    asort($myArray);

```
print_r($myArray);
```

Array ( [the first row] => Array ( [0] => AAAA ) [my last row] => Array ( [0] => ZZZZ [1] => AAAA ) )